# Using variable within JQuery selector

Tags: jquery

I have some code that saves a selector in a variable, which when testing works fine the first time I reference it (line 2 of my code), but when I try to add an h1 to it, seen on line 3 of my code, I get the following error: 
"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] h1"

How can I add an h1 to my variable in the selector without getting an error?

```
var $tabContentHeader = $('.tab-content-header');
var $headerLineHeight = $($tabContentHeader).height() + 10 + 'px';
$($tabContentHeader + ' h1').css({'line-height': $headerLineHeight});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row tab-content-header">
    <img src="images/content-area/page-header.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a1">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: please show your relevant html

Comment: There's no need for the second jQuery wrap: `$($tabContentHeader)`. Just stay with `$tabContentHeader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $tabContentHeader = $('.tab-content-header');
var $headerLineHeight = $($tabContentHeader).height() + 10 + 'px';
$tabContentHeader.find('h1').css({'line-height': $headerLineHeight});
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I have several instances of .tab-content-header h1, but this code appears to only change the first instance of it. How can I alter the code to get it to change all instances of .tab-content-header h1 at once?